# unable to see whole pdf file in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have view pager in my application.I am need to show PDF file on view pager.It shows a PDF file in view pager.I need to see whole PDF file at once .If i need to zoom i can do later.It doesn't show whole PDF file in view pager.I need to scroll down to see whole PDF file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic since it's about general computing software. You may want to try SuperUser.SE instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is the code from an app I built that shows a PDF.

I put the PDF in the raw folder.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;



public class book extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
    {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.book);
        CopyReadAssets();

            }




    private void CopyReadAssets()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "tintin.pdf");
        try
        {
            in = assetManager.open("tintin.pdf");
            out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/tintin.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any way to show PDF file from URL over LAN? So, I want to display http://192.168.2.3/file.pdf but it won't work with google docs solution.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure.  Why wont it work with google docs? Can you not save the on google docs and then open the url in web view? I've done this with spreadsheets.